# Django 2.0.2 - Many To Many Relation - Can't get IDs

Tags: python, json, django, fullcalendar, many-to-many

I've been trying to develop a webapplication with Django 2.0.2 including Full Calendar and Bitnami Stack. I seem to not comprehend the Many-to-Many relationship in Django. Currently I am attempting to match all fitting resourceIds with each corresponding event (called termin in this case):

views.py:

```
def events(request):
terminList = Termin.objects.all()
termine = []
for termin in terminList:
    termine.append({'title': termin.beschreibung,
                    'start': termin.startzeit,
                    'end': termin.endzeit,
                    'resourceId': str(termin.teilnehmer_betreuer.all()) ## Trying to get a Resource ID here ##
                    })
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(termine, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type='application/json')
```

models.py:

```
class Termin(models.Model):
GRUEN = 'GR'
GELB = 'GE'
ROT = 'RO'
UEBERSCHREIBBARKEIT_AUSWAHL = (
    (GRUEN, 'Überschreibbar'),
    (GELB, 'Auf Anfrage'),
    (ROT, 'Nicht Überschreibbar'),
)

startzeit = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
endzeit = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
beschreibung = models.TextField(max_length=400)
teilnehmer_patient = models.ManyToManyField(Patient)
teilnehmer_betreuer = models.ManyToManyField(Benutzer)
ueberschreibarkeit = models.CharField(
    max_length=25,
    choices=UEBERSCHREIBBARKEIT_AUSWAHL,
    default=GRUEN,
)
raum = models.ForeignKey(Raum, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.beschreibung
```

The json I get:

```
[{"title": "Test", "start": "2018-02-09T06:57:23Z", "end": "2018-02-09T07:20:00Z", "resourceId": "<QuerySet []>"}, {"title": "Test", "start": "2018-02-09T13:05:59Z", "end": "2018-02-09T13:05:59Z", "resourceId": "<QuerySet [<Benutzer: doktor>, <Benutzer: joschmidl>, <Benutzer: skywalker>, <Benutzer: qsdasdsada>]>"}, {"title": "Taesaed123", "start": "2018-02-09T13:06:21Z", "end": "2018-02-09T13:06:21Z", "resourceId": "<QuerySet [<Benutzer: doktor>, <Benutzer: joschmidl>, <Benutzer: skywalker>, <Benutzer: qsdasdsada>]>"}]
```

This is the extra table, which is not in my models.py, that Django creates after migrating my database.

```
id,termin_id,benutzer_id
7,2,2
8,2,4
9,2,5
10,2,6
4,3,2
2,3,4
5,3,5
6,3,6
```

What I don't understand is: Why can't I access it directly? Is there a way to do this? That would make it much easier.

Finally, what I want exactly is: Every benutzer_id that has the same termin_id should be appended to the json, so I can display each termin with every fitting benutzer. What do I have to type into the resource_id field to achieve this?

Comment: Well you certainly shouldn't be calling `str` on that queryset, for a start. But what *exactly* do you want in that value? Just a list of IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the following code:

```
'resourceIds': list(Termin.objects.filter(id=termin.id).values_list(str('teilnehmer_betreuer__id'), flat=True))
```

Comment: Note you don't need`str()` in `str` in `str('teilnehmer_betreuer__id')`. It's already a string.